# How should we go about retagging the salvaged posts?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-salvage, retagging

**UPDATE**  from D.Z.: I'm hijacking Manishearth's question to organize the tag cleanup effort, because most of the links are already posted here. Here's how this is going to work: whenever you have time and feel so inclined, go through the lists below and pick out a few questions (maybe no more than 5 at a time) that you want to review. Make sure the tags are appropriate, edit them if not, and try to make any other improvements that are warranted. When retagging, keep in mind:

- If a tag that was originally on the question doesn't exist here at Physics, but you think it would be appropriate (which it usually should be) check and see if we have a different tag with the same meaning. If not, feel free to recreate the same tag. If you don't have enough rep to create tags, just leave that post, or flag it for moderator attention.
- We have a list of [subfield tags](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/physics-subfield-tags-and-general-tag-rules) of which each post should probably have at least one. The list may be a little out of date, so consider it a guideline.

Each time you review a question and finish any edits necessary, delete it from the list below.

---

Alright.

Today(-ish), Astro.SE and TP.SE shall be mass-migrated to Phy.SE.

After the migration, we have retagging to consider--these questions will all be [untagged](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) ([list of questions that are "untagged"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged)).

**Note that the questions need reviewing as well.**

We shall be provided with a meta-post-list of the migrated questions.

### How should we retag?

The issue with retagging is that it bumps the post, flooding our poor main page (and drowning out 'normal' edits/posts).

One way to handle this is to just disregard the main page and have the joint communities go on a retagging spree, keeping track of it in a copy of the meta post list.

The other way is similar to [Tag cleanup--[light]](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1166/tag-cleanup-light), and is much more relaxed on  the main page.

- Duplicate the meta post, maybe split into chunks for cleanliness
- Start retagging. Make sure that you do few enough to not flood the main page. We'll have to decide exactly what 'few enough' means. (I use 5 at a time for the [light] cleanup)
  -Remove retagged post links from the meta post. (or maybe mark as 'done'?)
- If our self-imposed 'rate limit' has been reached, then just go about adding tags to the entry in the meta post. That way, someone who knows less about the topic can still retag. (I can get you a `[tag:...]` keyboard shortcut if you like the pretty tag formatting)
- **Try to improve the post as well.** Review it to fit our site better.

Well, that's how I *think* it should be. We may want to work out the details--this is a big job.

### Other issues with retagging

The [research-level] tag is still under debate(I think). We may want to refrain from retagging TP questions till we decide on this. Or, we can go  ahead with normal retagging and let the SE folks auto add it to the listed questions if possible.

New tags: All these questions may need new tags, especially Astro ones. We may want to first have a look at the questions and decide which tags to create. Unchecked, this can bloat our already-bloated tag list.

Site matter: we may not have that many users who know the subject well enough (eg me). These guys may not be able to *choose* the tags, but they can do the actual retagging. We need to engage the Astro and TP communities here for choosing tags.

Alternatively, I can write a script which compares the contents of the editor with  the tag list and suggests tags. Though that may take a while (few days, got other things to do atm)

Basically, we need to [discuss](/questions/tagged/discuss) this and decide what steps, as a community, we shall take.

Comment: Why not  relabel the tags before they are migrated (by addinfg a T oresp A to theold tag name) so that all tags can migrate. Then one has the old classification intect and can merge tags later at leisure.

Comment: @Arnold the tags aren't being copied over, and it's too late to change this. I'd asked Shog9 about this--he said previous site-merges have gotten by with a metapost-list. Though on investigation those were smaller scale :/

Comment: The hard truth is that every migrated question needs to be reviewed *anyway*. Slapping an intrinsic tag on them doesn't change this.

Comment: @Shog aah, makes sense. I think I'll add that..

Comment: Are there any specific style/consistency changes that need done overall; or is it mostly taking advantage of the need to retag to force a copy edit pass over all the new content at the same time?

Comment: Addendum: It's been a while since I did this en masse, and so I'd forgotten how tags on the source that don't exist on the destination get stripped. This doesn't change the need to visit all incoming questions, but does increase the need. On the bright side, you avoid the mass introduction of tags that don't fit your tagging scheme.

Comment: It seems the posts came complete with sensible tags...

Comment: @Dan I don't think so, not other than the tags.

Comment: I think we are a go for using research-level. http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/capturing-theoretical-physics-crowd-with-research-level-tag

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky and Manishearth: For someone relatively new to the site like me, I'm confused. Is the retagging done? I see lists of imported questions from Shog9 - are these the ones people were supposed to delete upon retagging?

Comment: @ChrisWhite it's not done, it's an ongoing project, and it's going rather slowly at that. But if you want to help out, then sure, you pick a question from the answers here, check that it has appropriate tags (including [tag:research-level] for TP questions), and remove it from the list when you're done. The original complete lists of questions are [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/questions-imported-from-astronomy-and-theoretical-physics).

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky So I went through a few (I'll try not to flood the feed - I don't suppose there's any way to not bump when changing a tag), but I seem to be blocked from editing the below posts.

Comment: @Chris huh, well, you should be able to suggest edits, although they have to be approved by someone else until you get 2000 reputation. There should be a notice at the top of the edit page letting you know about this ("Your edit will be placed in a queue until it can be peer reviewed" etc.) If you're having some other problem, I'd suggest making a new meta post to describe the details of the problem you're having and ask what's going on.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I can retag just fine. I meant on this page. I can't suggest edits to Shog9's answers, with the message "Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites." I guess they need to be CW? Or am I trying to do something wrong?

Comment: Oh, that's what you mean. It's just what the message says. I'll make the question and answers CW so you can edit them.

Answer (score 4):

#### Astronomy imports: 1 of 5

Completed reviewing..! The original version can be found [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/questions-imported-from-astronomy-and-theoretical-physics/1249#1249)...

Answer (score 4):

#### Astronomy imports: 2 of 5

The following posts were migrated here from Astronomy. The original tags are listed below each link.

<sup><sub>Split among 5 answers due to length</sub></sup>

**Edit:** Finished reviewing. The original list can be found [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/questions-imported-from-astronomy-and-theoretical-physics/1253#1250).

Comment: AAH MY MULTICOLLIDER™ INBOX!

Comment: Seriously though, could these be moved to a separate post? This one is for discussing 'em and the page is flooded . :/

Comment: eh, fair enough

Comment: @Manishearth I'm going to undelete these so that we can use them to organize the retagging effort.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: Undelete what? They seem to be not-deleted already...

Comment: The answers Shog9 posted on this question had been deleted until I undeleted them yesterday.

Answer (score 4):

#### Theoretical Physics imports: 1 of 3

The following posts were migrated here from Theoretical Physics. The original tags are listed below each link.

<sup><sub>Split among 3 answers due to length</sub></sup>

```
Finished !
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Theoretical Physics imports: 2 of 3

The following posts were migrated here from Theoretical Physics. The original tags are listed below each link.

<sup><sub>Split among 3 answers due to length</sub></sup>

```
Finished !
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Theoretical Physics imports: 3 of 3

The following posts were migrated here from Theoretical Physics. The original tags are listed below each link.

<sup><sub>Split among 3 answers due to length</sub></sup>

```
Finished !
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Astronomy imports: 3 of 5

The following posts were migrated here from Astronomy. The original tags are listed below each link.

<sup><sub>Split among 5 answers due to length</sub></sup>

**Edit:** Completed reviewing. The original set could be found [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1251).

Answer (score 2):

#### Astronomy imports: 4 of 5

The following posts were migrated here from Astronomy. The original tags are listed below each link.

<sup><sub>Split among 5 answers due to length</sub></sup>

**Edit:** Last batch of astro imports completed! The original list can be found [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/questions-imported-from-astronomy-and-theoretical-physics/1252#1252).

Answer (score 2):

#### Astronomy imports: 5 of 5

The following posts were migrated here from Astronomy. The original tags are listed below each link.

<sup><sub>Split among 5 answers due to length</sub></sup>

**Edit:** Finished reviewing! The original list can be found [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/questions-imported-from-astronomy-and-theoretical-physics/1253#1253).