# The main page acting strange and inconsistently

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, site-salvage

Right now *(May 4th '12 20:58 UTC),* the main page either remains as I first opened it or continues to 'update' with tens of questions **each second** coming to the top of the list. Once I refresh, it's gone and everything is back to how it was when I first opened it; a minute later and the same behavior shows.

***Update:***

1. The posts that come up are very old (mostly dated between *May '11* and *Nov. '11*) if that helps...
2. It only happens when I stay on the main page.

Comment: I also don't see a reason for a down vote here, but just so that you know (1) the site specific metas do not have there own reputation, so downvotes here cost you nothing and (2) on meta dowvotes means disagreement, not that the post is ill constructed or inappropriate.

Comment: @dmckee, I deleted my comment just a moment ago! Otherwise, I'd already noticed that it doesn't cost reputation (although I'm not sure if up-votes increase it) but it was that I reported a bug and expected a confirmation/denial or so. I'm just letting it go now and will report if it continues tomorrow.  - I cleaned the question if that helped.

Comment: I wish I was online to see this.. I have a script which makes the realtime update bar click itself, which means where would have been a river of posts :)

Comment: @Manishearth, regardless of the reason of this post, I'm interested in that script generally. Could you ping me on chat or provide a link to its page?

Comment: @M.Na'el: `javascript:setInterval(function(){$('.new-post-activity').click()},10)` in a bookmarklet/browser URL bar. Make the 10 into a one if you want it the fastest. 10 means that it checks for and clicks(if the new post thingy is present) the new post thingy every ten milliseconds.

Answer (score 11):

Over a thousand questions were imported from the now-closed Astronomy and Theoretical Physics sites. We did this as quickly and unobtrusively as possible, but for a short while there simply were a huge number of new posts entering the site and the activity monitor reacted accordingly.

This is now completed, you should see no unusual activity... At least until folks start [retagging](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1235/how-should-we-go-about-retagging-the-salvaged-posts)...

Answer (score 8):

What you're seeing is apparently noise from the mass imports from astronomy and theoretical physics.

[What do you need to know about the upcoming mass migration?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/what-do-you-need-to-know-about-the-upcoming-mass-migration)

From what you described apparently the mass import process was adding questions and then pulling them off the front page, instead of adding them in a way they never appeared there in the first place.  That's less than ideal; but for a very rarely used feature putting effort into fine tuning it probably doesn't make sense.

Comment: I never meant to criticize anybody's work on the merging but I only reported what I saw. Since all he questions appeared physics to me (and I honestly wasn't interested in the merging), I thought it was a bug. I think _I_ may be bugging the mods here lately O:)

Comment: While it seems you're correct; the link you provided talked about noise because of 'intersection between question levels' which they said will be addressed by a 'research-grade' tag. It doesn't mention anything about technical noise but I don't see a reason to talk more of it. Thanks.

Comment: This is the correct answer here. Presumably all this will end fairly soon.